# Where has CsvClassMap.TypeConverterOption gone?

Tags: csvhelper

I'm upgrading some legacy code that uses the Nuget CsvHelper package.
The old version was 2.13.2, the new version is 9.0.0.
Lots of APIs have changed.  The old `CsvClassMap` class has become `ClassMap`.
On the old class, it used to be possible to specify type-converter options for individual fields:

```
public class MyClassMap : CsvClassMap<MyRecord>
{
  public MyClassMap()
  {
    Map(m => m.TimeStamp).TypeConverterOption(DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
    ...
```

The method `TypeConverterOption` no longer exists on the new `ClassMap` class, and so far (using DotPeek etc) I haven't identified an obvious replacement.  How does one go about specifying type conversion options for individual fields within a class map using CsvHelper version 9?  Is it still possible?

Answer (score 0):

Josh Close replied to my same question elsewhere (thank you!).  [This is what he said](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1160):

It's a namespace now with a bunch of methods for options. I ran out of overloads with the previous method. This allows for specific methods for each type of options.

```
Map(m => m.TimeStamp).TypeConverterOption.DateTimeStyles(DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```